# Only welcome controller loading in codeigniter when hosted under cpanel

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

The app which i'm creating using codeigniter is loading on my localhost. But when i uploaded the same into cpanel its showing "**404 Page Not Found**".

I'm able to access default welcome controller other than this it shows 404 page not found.

Below are my configuration in application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

.htaccess configurations are as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

configuration in application/config/routes.php are as below

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'login';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

If I change the default_controller to welcome then welcome is loading fine.

--Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure your controller's filenames are ucfirst

Comment: Thanks @AdrienXL. This fixed my problem

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comments : Your controller's file name must start with an uppercase.
See http://codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html

> Changed filenaming convention (class file names now must be Ucfirst
>   and everything else in lowercase).

:-)

Comment: This is only the case if you're using CodeIgniter 3.